# Возможно ли сделать DependencyProperty типа коллекции, чтобы применялась OneWayToSource привязка?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кастомный контрол. В нём есть DependencyProperty:

```
    public IList MySelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(MySelectedItemsProperty); }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                SetValue(MySelectedItemsProperty, value);
            }
            else
            {
                ClearValue(MySelectedItemsProperty);
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MySelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MySelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(MyGridControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

который дополнительно инициализируется в конструкторе

```
    public MyGridControl()
    {
        MySelectedItems = new ObservableCollectionCore<object>();
    }
```

работа с ним ведется в обработчике события таким образом:

```
        if (MySelectedItems != null)
        {
            MySelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (int index in OrderedSelection)
            {
                if ((bool)_selection[index])
                {
                    MySelectedItems.Add(GetRowByListIndex(index));
                }
            }
            MySelectedItemsCount = MySelectedItems.Count;
        }
```

К нему в контексте привязано свойство, объявленное так:

```
private ObservableCollection<TestData> _selectedData = new ObservableCollection<TestData>();
public ObservableCollection<TestData> SelectedData
    {
        get { return _selectedData; }
        set
        {
            _selectedData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedData));
        }
    }
```

через привязку в xaml

```
<local:MyGridControl MySelectedItems="{Binding Path=SelectedData}" />
```

Всё это работает. Однако меня интересует вопрос, возможно ли каким-то образом изменить код так, чтобы в xaml применялась привязка:

```
MySelectedItems="{Binding Path=SelectedData, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

На данный момент, если я пытаюсь это сделать, то MySelectedItems инициализуруется null'ом. Почему так происходит и можно ли это изменить?

Comment: а чем оно должно было инициализироваться?

Comment: @tym32167 Сначала инициализация идет значением по умолчанию из PropertyMetadata. Затем дополнительно в конструкторе пустой коллекцией. Если убрать привязку в xaml, пустая коллекция и останется. Если же добавить привезку в xaml с Mode=OneWayToSource, происходит доп. инициализация null'ом, независимо от значения SelectedData.

Comment: `OneWayToSource` подразумевает, что свойству `MySelectedItems` вообще без разницы что там в `SelectedData`, разве нет?

Comment: @tym32167 вопрос не об этом, а почему MySelectedItems инициализируется null'ом, несмотря на прямую инициализацию конструктором, если применить OneWayToSource

Comment: поставьте брейкпоинт на сеттере и поглядите кто кго вызывает

Comment: @tym32167 про какой сеттер речь? если про MySelectedItems, то он вызывается единожды, из конструктора. Инициализация из PropertyMetadata и последующее обнулление происходит без участия сеттера.

Comment: Зачем вообще городить такой огород? Если вам не нужно, чтобы контрол менял свое содержимое, когда вы изменяете коллецию, можете использовать не `ObservableCollection` а простой `List`. Я даже представить не могу, какую задачу вы хотите с таким изяществом решить. С другой стороны, если вы используете биндинги и MVVM, зачем вам обработчики событий? И наоборот. Смешивая методики реализации вы только запутаете себя и наплодите багов. Если расскажете, в чем задача, зачем именно нужен `OneWayToSource`, быть может я вам подскажу другое решение.

Comment: @aepot извините, я думал, это очевидно, что контрол кастомный, раз есть объявление DependencyProperty. я уточнил это в вопросе. обработчик события - в кастомном контроле он изменяет MySelectedItems. MVVM для view, на котором используется этот контрол. SelectedData каким-то образом должен узнать, что MySelectedItems изменились. Если у вас есть решение, при котором List получит информацию о том, что MySelectedItems изменились внутри контрола, пожалуйста, расскажите мне о нем.

Comment: Так понятнее, спасибо. А вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122595/how-do-you-create-a-read-only-dependency-property) случаем не в тему?

Comment: @aepot объявление readonly property убивает возможность сделать к нему binding через xaml. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658170/onewaytosource-binding-from-readonly-property-in-xaml/658683#658683

Comment: Согласен, не полумал об этом, ну тогда быть может [это](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+wpf+selecteditems+mvvm+site:stackoverflow.com)?